# Insert element in List with AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to load some JSON inside my Android App. On the MainActivity I have created one AsyncTask to download the JSON and to Parse it. Everything here works, but I have a problem to put everything inside a ListView.

I have created a Model (with 6 Strings) and the Adapter.
The problem is, I can't update the List with the new content inside the "doInBackground" function, and I don't know how to put everything inside the list.

Comment: Hey, a simple Google search would have put you on the right track but hey, no worries. There you go -> http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Adapter is set up properly to listen to a List as its data source, then you will simply need to change the elements in the List and then notify the Adapter by calling one of the notify methods, such as `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

However, since this is modifying UI elements, this will need to be run on the UI thread. The `doInBackground()` method of an AsyncTask is run on a separate thread than the UI thread so we need to do one of two things:

- Wait until we're done in the separate thread and then notify the adapter
- Tell the UI thread to notify the adapter

The first is easily done if we call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onPostExecuted` method of an AsyncTask.

The second is easily done if we have a reference to an Activity object, by calling the `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground()` method didn't have access to UI thread, so you can't do it. In your case you should update your `ListView` in `onPostExecute` method or you can use for this `runOnUiThread()` method directly in your `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update or put data in listview in **doInBackground()** method. You have to assign **Adpter** to **Listview**, **onCreate()** method of **MainActivity** and **onPostExecute()** Method update listview. I have posted below code snippet will be helpful.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String json_string;
JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONArray jsonArray;
ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new BackegroundTask().execute();
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);

    listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);



}

class BackegroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
    String json_url;
    String JSON_STRING;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        json_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/index.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        json_string = result;

        try {
            jsonObject  = new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            int count = 0;
            String id,username;
            while (count<jsonArray.length()){
                JSONObject job = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                id = job.getString("id");
                username = job.getString("username");
                Contacts contacts = new Contacts(id,username);
                contactAdapter.add(contacts);
                contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                count++;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```